# Client Side Validation for document library forms

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, validation, forms-library

I wish to do Client Side Validation for document library forms. I have tried doing it using jquery for List forms and it is working fine. But when i tried this for Document Library forms, it's not working. Will it not work for document libraries?
Any suggestions would be appreciable.

Comment: Are you adding validation in editform.aspx in document library?

Comment: Yes Sabitha i am adding validation in editform.aspx in document library.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the "New Experience" Document Library UI?

If so, then it won't accept any branding, or custom script. Microsoft has disabled everything.

The current answer from Microsoft is: Switch back to Classic Mode

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Differences-between-the-new-document-library-experience-and-classic-mode-30e1aab0-a5cc-4363-b7f2-09e2ae07d4dc?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: Thanks for replying Danny. Microsoft isn't letting me to turn on the old classic experience now. Also i am able to apply validations in my share point lists but not libraries specifically.